# Azure Pipeline Problem: The Trigger of Repository of Resources Does Not Work

Tags: azure-pipelines, cicd, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a pipeline and the yaml file is in a repo called Pipelines. I want to trigger it when another repo, assumed RepoA, is updated. I have review the document from here:

[Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops)

According to the example in the document above, I build my pipeline as the code below:

```
# YAML: Pipelines/test-pipeline.yml
trigger:
- develop

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: A
    type: git
    name: RepoA
    ref: main
    trigger:
    - main
    - develop

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: A
```

and I assume the pipeline would work as this circomstance:

| Change made to | Pipeline triggered | Version of YAML | Version of self | Version of A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `develop` in `self` | Yes | commit from `develop` that triggered the pipeline | commit from `develop` that triggered the pipeline | latest from `main` |
| `main` in `A` | Yes | latest from `main` | latest from `main` | commit from `main` that triggered the pipeline |
| `develop` in `A` | Yes | latest from `main` | latest from `main` | commit from `develop` that triggered the pipeline |

However, the truth is the update in RepoA would not fire the pipeline. Did I miss something in the rules of pipeline or project settings?

### Try 1: add the project name of RepoA

```
trigger:
- develop

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: A
    type: git
    name: MyProject/RepoA
    ref: main
    trigger:
    - main
    - develop

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: A
```

#### Result:

not work (p.s. Repo Pipelines and RepoA are under the same project)

### Try 2: add refs/heads/ before the trigger branches of RepoA

#### Result:

not work

### Try 3: set trigger format as below

```
trigger:
- develop

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: A
    type: git
    name: MyProject/RepoA
    ref: main
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
          - main
          - develop

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: A
```

#### Result:

not work

Answer (score 0):

I used your first yaml, and repository trigger works（test1 as repo A）：

[image]

[image]

Please follow below steps:

1. Change the `develop` branch as **default branch** in the repo.
2. If the pipeline didn't run before, please manually run it for one time.

Then commit on repo A to check the trigger(PS: if repo A is in same project, use `name: RepoA` in yaml for trigger, without project.)

Edit:

Add my yaml:

```
trigger:
- dev5

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: A
    type: git
    name: test1
    ref: main
    trigger:
    - main
    - develop


steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: A
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. However, I had tried both advices and it still does not work. Is there any setting about policies or security in project settings that had to be set for the repo? Btw, in your case, would this pipeline be triggered if you update the develop branch instead of main branch? Thanks.

Comment: @YuLun, there's no other policies or security setting to set. I confirm the repository resource trigger works fine when i commit for both `main` and `develop` branches in `test1`(repoA). Please edit your yaml pipeline ->click vertical 3 dots on the tog right -> Triggers -> On `Triggers` tab, make sure `override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here` is NOT selected. If the trigger still doesn't work, please remove the trigger on your yaml -> save -> add the resource trigger again->save to update, will it work then? Also try with same yaml in another project, will the trigger work?

Comment: Need to mention is the `develop` branch which set as default branch is in your yaml repo, not the develop branch in repo A.

Comment: Hello @wade , thank you for replying. I do confirm that the "override the YAML continous integration trigger from there" is not selected. As for second method, I think I have redone it for many times. I will try the third method, maybe with two new repositories. At least I get that the problem is not on Azure but myself, then I would find the solution some day, I guess. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @YuLun, one possible cause is there're some syntax error in your yaml, which cannot be evaluated by devops(we see this before which cause resource trigger not work), hence, i edit my reply and share the yaml sample, please create a new yaml in your repo(default branch), copy my yaml, change the branch name, check if it works for you.

Comment: Hello @wade. If there are some syntax error, I think the pipeline cannot work. However, I can run it manually and get the resources in repository A. It's just can not be trigger by the update in A automatically.(It's also the one confuse me the most. How can the pipeline get the resource correctly but can not be triggered ?) In a word, I would try your yaml and let you know. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @YuLun, it could happen that some syntax exists but manual run works, only resource trigger doesn't work, we receive similar report before. Yes please copy my yaml, and only change the repo & branch named to yours for a check.

Comment: @YuLun, may i know if the yaml works?

Comment: thank you for your help. I apologize for replying late. The result is still unfortunate. My pipeline does not be triggered by the change of repoA. Since this is a project according to my business, i cannot just put my code to here. For now, i give up this way and put the yaml file with my repoA. It works well. The reason i try to put my yaml file in another repo is that i can edit it without commit to the repo so that the project directory would be much clean. Though the way now i used looks awful (cry), it works ok. I will keep trying to figure out the reason. Thank you for your help.